# Update images created by ng-repeat using directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-directive

I use sockte.io to get my data from the server, and depends of the data(item.text) I have to change the images.
I tried to acces to the DOM and modify the image using a Directive but no luck.

This my code:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items"  myDirective>
        <td><img  ng-src="{{myImages}}" ></td> <td>{{item.text}}</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

JS:

```
App.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    link: function($scope, elm){
      console.log('eee', elm);
      elm[0]['children'][0]['children'][0].attr('src',"/url/to/the/image");
    }
  }
});
```

How can I fix that, or if there is a better way to do that.

**UPDATE:**

At a given time the images are not the same, I want to acces to the index of each image using their index.

**UPDATE:**
I added this [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mils/4bg2zLq2/10/), how can I modify for  example the image that have 'text 2'

Comment: in your fiddle there is only one image-address: `http://www.exlibrisgroup.com/fr/files/Products/question_icon.gif` should that be an array?

Comment: This is not all my code, I updated already the EXAMPLE(just I added a new image) and I want to update just the 'text 2' with this image. How can I do that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lgwjj3m2/ ?

Comment: That will help for sure. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need a directive for this. Use [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) instead of the normal `src` attribute for images.

Comment: at a given time the images are not the same, is that possible with ng-src?

Comment: if you mean that the `myImages` variable in `ng-src="myImages"` is updated somewhere else, then yes it is possible.